# Accessing "this" as the parent from callbacks emberjs nested component

Tags: ember.js, dropzone.js

I have a parent component whose template contains a dropzone component from https://www.npmjs.com/ember-cli-dropzonejs:

```
{{drop-zone url='#' addRemoveLinks=true success=fileReceived}}
```

In the parent controller, I have a method called `fileReceived` which is being called when the success event triggers on the dropzone. However, I would like to call other methods which are stored on the controller when the `fileReceived` method is called but I cannot access `this`. I tried setting an instance variable called `self` to `this` on `didInsertElement`, but it gives me window instead of my component.

This is my parent component controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  self:null,
  didInsertElement:function()
  {
    this.set('self', this);
  },
  fileReceived: function (file) {
    //Validate sheet

    this.sendAction('doStuff', file); //"this" returns a dropzone object instead of parentObject
    //this.doStuff(file);
  },
  actions: {
    doStuff: function (file) {
      //do stuff with the file
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `fileReceived` should be within actions, and then `this.sendAction` should be `this.send`. Then I think this will be the thing you want?

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    fileReceived: function (file) {
        //Validate sheet

        this.send('doStuff', file); //"this" returns a dropzone object instead of parentObject
        //this.doStuff(file);
  },
    doStuff: function (file) {
      //do stuff with the file
  }
});
```

**Edit**:

As discussed in comments you also needed to change your template to

```
{{drop-zone url='#' addRemoveLinks=true success=(action 'fileReceived')}}
```

Comment: I did try that and thought that it didn't work. I just tried it again and realised that I need to make my template look like this: `{{drop-zone url='#' addRemoveLinks=true success=(action 'fileReceived')}}`. Now it is picking up the action and seems to be working.

Comment: Was about to suggest trying `{{drop-zone url='#' addRemoveLinks=true success="fileReceived"}}`, but your syntax above is better for newer Ember